# why cant i invoke public method from a custom object returned from NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, nsarray

so what i'm doing is to try and get the value of an array at index i, when tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called. when i debug it, i actually see my object as my custom object but i cant access its methods.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // some code to get the cell here   

    id dilemaView = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];
    DilemaUIView * dv = (DilemaUIView *)dilemaView;

    if([dilemaView isKindOfClass:[DilemaUIView class]]){
        cell.imageView.image = [dilemaView getLeftImage];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

the problem is that isKindOfClass always returns NO. where am i wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Where are you loading your self.dataArray array add source code

Comment: before entering this view, i also see the my custom object in debug mode

Comment: if it fails always objects are in self.dataArray is not DilemaUIView class. Show me the snippet where you are allocatting and adding objects to it

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([dilemaView class]));` and see if you are getting the Classname or, not.

Comment: iDev - i've tried what iphonic suggested and i see that the objects are of type UIImageView. also, im initing it like this:

Comment: i have a other controller that holds the object, then adding it to an array:
self.chatsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if(nil != self.chatView)
        [self.chatsArray addObject:self.chatView];
then im passing it to this controller in custom init method, and assigning it like this:
self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayData];

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please try to check `dv` instead of `dilemaview`.

```
if([dv isKindOfClass:[DilemaUIView class]]){
        cell.imageView.image = [dilemaView getLeftImage];
    }
```

Comment: Please try to print this line NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([dv class]));

Comment: for some reason, they both UIImageView, which i can't understand why

Comment: Let me know the superclass of DilemaUIView ?? & its little bit code

Comment: @Max You got the solution by superclass trik?

Comment: Nothing if you got any clue by me then accept this answer.

Comment: Your answer is nonsense. isKindOfClass doesn't care about the declared type of the object you are passing in, passing an id works just as fine as passing anything else.

Answer (score -1):

thanks for your help guys. i think i found the problem - when i create the DilemaUIView which is inherited from UIView, i set self like this:

```
self = (DilemaUIView*)imageView;
```

where imageView is of type UIImageView. thats why i cant cast it back to it. 
actually now its even simpler cause i wanted to get the image out of it and now i can just use

```
cell.imageView.image = dv.image;
```

thanks a lot!